# скрытие меню при клике вне кнопки JQuery

Tags: html, css, jquery

Я не могу понять почему при клике вне dropdown ничего не происходит

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Radio+Canada:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .content {
      width: 200px;
      font-family: 'Radio Canada';
      font-size: 30px;
      margin: 0 0 0 -40px;
      background: rgb(208, 255, 119);
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
    }
    
    .content:hover {
      background: rgb(218, 255, 148);
    }
    
    .btn {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      font-family: 'Radio Canada';
      text-align: left;
      background: rgb(208, 255, 119);
      border: 3px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .btn.active {
      border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    }
    
    .btn::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 2px;
      background: black;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      margin: 13px 0 0 150px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .btn::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 2px;
      background: black;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      margin: 13px 0 0 27px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      background: rgb(214, 255, 139);
    }
    
    .btn.active::after {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .btn.active::before {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    
    .list {
      margin: -16px 0 0 0;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .content.last {
      border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
      border-bottom: 3px solid black;
      border-left: 3px solid black;
      border-right: 3px solid black;
    }
    
    .content.first {
      border-top: 0px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>dropdown</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div><button class='btn'>dropdown</button></div>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li><button class="content first">menu</button></li>
      <li><button class="content">menu</button></li>
      <li><button class="content">menu</button></li>
      <li><button class="content">menu</button></li>
      <li><button class="content last">menu</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.btn').click(function() {
        $('.list').slideToggle(500);
        $('.btn, .btn::before, .btn::after').toggleClass('active')
      });
      let a = $('.btn')
      let b = $('.list')

      $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!a.is(e.target) && a.has(e.target).lenght === 0 &&
          !b.is(e.target) && b.has(e.target).lenght === 0
        ) {
          b.slideUp(500);
          a.removeClass('active')
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Две опечатки. lenght -> length

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка при написании свойства - length

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в строке
"$(document).click(function(e) {".
Нельзя так писать.
Можно писать, к примеру
"$(document).on("click",".list",function() {"

Comment: Что хначит нельзя? Всё можно.